# How can I pipe a command into the meteor shell?

Tags: shell, meteor

Let's say I have a few directories, each running a different branch of a Meteor development server. I could `cd` to each directory, run `meteor shell`, and type a command. And that's great for 2 or 3 directories, but what if I have 10? 100?

Is there some equivalent of

```
meteor shell < 'DoJSThing()`
```

that I can script from the command line, so that I can use<sup>[1]</sup>

```
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && meteor shell "doJSThing()" ); done
```

---

**[1]** *[source for bash `for` loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171677/cd-into-all-directories-execute-command-on-files-in-that-directory-and-return)*

Comment: This will be part of a future release. See [this PR](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/5575).

Comment: Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the latest Meteor (I'm currently testing on 1.3), you can indeed use the syntax provided in that pull request:

```
$ echo Meteor.isServer | meteor shell
true
```

You can also write your JS to a file and use the `<` syntax to pipe into stdin:

```
$ meteor shell < myfile
```

It's worth noting that if you name your JS file with a .js extension, it'll auto-load into the running Meteor app, which is potentially, but probably *not*, what you want.