# How to call a Meteor method from the command line

Tags: meteor, methods, command-line

I have a Meteor app and want to call a server method from the command line, so that I can write a bash script to perform scheduled operations.

Is there any way to either call a method directly, or submit a form which will then trigger server-side code?

I've tried using curl to call a method, but either it's not possible or I'm missing something basic. This doesn't work:

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/Meteor.call('myMethod')"
```

nor does:

```
curl -s -d "http://localhost:3000/imports/api/test.js" > out.html
```

where test.js:

```
var test = function(){
    console.log('hello');
}
```

I thought of using a form but I can't think how to create a submit event because the Meteor client uses template events that then call server methods.

I'll be very grateful for any help! This feels like it should be a simple thing but has me stumped.

Edit: I've also tried phantomjs and slimerjs as run through casperjs.

phantomjs is no longer maintained and generates an error:

`TypeError: Attempting to change the setter of an unconfigurable property`.

https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/1935

slimerjs errors with Firefox 60 and I can't figure out how to 'downgrade' back to the supported 59, and the option to disable automatic updates of Firefox no longer seems to exist. The error is:

```
c is undefined
```

https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs/issues/694

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make use of the [node ddp package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ddp) to call the Meteor method in an own js file that you created with a specific script. From there you can pipe all outs to wherever you want.

Let's assume the following Meteor method:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  'myMethod'() {
    console.log("hello console")
    return "hello result"
  }
})
```

The upcoming steps will let you call this method from another shell, assuming your Meteor application is running.

**1. Install ddp in your global npm directory**

```sh
$ meteor npm install -g ddp
```

**2. Create the script to call your method in your test directory**

```sh
$ mkdir -p  ddptest
$ cd ddptest
$ touch ddptest.js
```

Place the ddp script code into the file with the editor or command of your choice.
 (The follwing code is freely taken from the package's readme. Feel free to configure to your needs.)

*ddptest/ddptest.js*

```js
var DDPClient = require(process.env.DDP_PATH);

var ddpclient = new DDPClient({
  // All properties optional, defaults shown
  host : "localhost",
  port : 3000,
  ssl  : false,
  autoReconnect : true,
  autoReconnectTimer : 500,
  maintainCollections : true,
  ddpVersion : '1',  // ['1', 'pre2', 'pre1'] available
  // uses the SockJs protocol to create the connection
  // this still uses websockets, but allows to get the benefits
  // from projects like meteorhacks:cluster
  // (for load balancing and service discovery)
  // do not use `path` option when you are using useSockJs
  useSockJs: true,
  // Use a full url instead of a set of `host`, `port` and `ssl`
  // do not set `useSockJs` option if `url` is used
  url: 'wss://example.com/websocket'
}); 

ddpclient.connect(function(error, wasReconnect) {
  // If autoReconnect is true, this callback will be invoked each time
  // a server connection is re-established
  if (error) {
    console.log('DDP connection error!');
    console.error(error)
    return;
  }

  if (wasReconnect) {
    console.log('Reestablishment of a connection.');
  }

  console.log('connected!');

  setTimeout(function () {
    /*
     * Call a Meteor Method
     */
    ddpclient.call(
      'myMethod',             // namyMethodme of Meteor Method being called
      ['foo', 'bar'],            // parameters to send to Meteor Method
      function (err, result) {   // callback which returns the method call results
        console.log('called function, result: ' + result);
        ddpclient.close();
      },
      function () {              // callback which fires when server has finished
        console.log('updated');  // sending any updated documents as a result of
        console.log(ddpclient.collections.posts);  // calling this method
      }
    );
  }, 3000);
});
```

The code assumes that your app runs on `localhost:3000`, note that there is no conncection close on errors or undesired behavior.

As you can see at the top, the file imports your globally installed ddp package. Now in order to get it's path without using additional tools, just pass an environment variable (`process.env.DDP_PATH`) and let your shell handle the path resolving.

In order to get the installation path you can use `npm root` with the global flag.

Finally call your script via:

```sh
$ DDP_PATH=$(meteor npm root -g)/ddp meteor node ddptest.js
```

Which will give you the following output:

```sh
connected!
updated
undefined
called function, result: hello result
```

And logs `hello console` to the open session that is running your meteor app.

#### Edit: A note on using this in production

If you want to use this script in production you have to use the shell commands without the `meteor` command but using your installation of `node` and `npm`.

If you get in trouble with paths use `process.execPath` to find your node binary and `npm root -g` to find your global npm modules.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed and clear answer. I've tried this out and it seems to be exactly what I need.

Comment: Please check out the answer of @FlissHou and if it works you may rather accept it as meteor shell is directly build for such purposes as yours.

Comment: I only just noticed that your answer seems to use the meteor shell. Would it work on a production build?

Comment: Yes the code above should work in production as it can be run without having the meteor framework installed on the server but only the node runtime. Edit: I will edit my post with a comment.

Comment: Thank you, can you give an example please of how the command would look for production? DDP_PATH=$(npm root -g)/ddp node ddptest.js gives an error "Cannot find module '/home/user/Meteor/ddptest.js'"

Comment: Ah, I have not yet made a production build, I'm investigating solutions while still in dev. That may be part of the problem.

Comment: `DDP_PATH=$(npm root -g)/ddp node ddptest.js` assumes `ddptest.js` is in the current folder. Otherwise specify `DDP_PATH=$(npm root -g)/ddp node path/to/ddptest.js`. Regarding `process.execPath` -> this works only in a node shell or in a running js script that is interpreted by node. `process` is [part of node](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/process.html#process_process). It is easier to get the path to node within than searching using whereis if you have multiple versions installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this documentation: [Command Line | meteor shell](https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorshell).

While your meteor app is running, you can execute `meteor shell` to start an interactive console. In the console, you can do `Meteor.call(...)`.

So if you want to write a script with using `meteor shell`, you might need to pipe the script file for `meteor shell`. Like,

```
$ meteor shell < script_file
```

See also the answer of "[How can I pipe a command into the meteor shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36289850/6440904)"

Comment: Would this work when running a production build, i.e. Meteor is not installed?

Comment: @LittleBrain I didn't really try it on production build, but I assume it wouldn't work without meteor installed.